# BMD Database Schema

Tags: mysql, sql, database, schema, database-schema

Okay, so this problem is stumping me somewhat and I would appreciate some help from someone regarding normalisation (and the end goal of having the ability to search all records at once) if at all possible.

I'm trying to construct a database schema that holds birth, baptism, marriage, death & burial records, as entered from original 1800's documents.
Each record type has unique information that needs to be recorded so as it stands I have a table for each type. Please have a look at the following draft schema;

[image]

The obvious data to normalise in the three tables I've used in the example (tbBaptism, tbMarriage, tbBurial) are the location, the church and the source as I have done in that draft schema. Ideally the person would also be normalised into their own table, but with the data I am dealing with, it is not possible to identify all individuals.

Now the problem (if indeed it is actually a problem?) is I feel like there must be a better way of storing the data in the tables tbBaptism, tbMarriage, tbBurial ... perhaps combining them into one table? ... possibly an event table which has the common fields such as the event date, location, church, etc. but how would I store the unique fields such as marriage witnesses for example?

Am I trying to over simplify things and is the current draft schema is the way to go?

I'm looking for ideas/suggestions that will make my life easier in the long run!!

Comment: I think I would still extract people and their dependent data into separate tables, even though records wouldn't correspond 1-to-1 with actual people.  Location looks like it could be transitively dependent on church.  Baptisms, marriages and burials, though they have attributes in common, are different predicates and so I wouldn't want to combine into one table.